# How to acess fields in other model using relational field in view (odoo)

Tags: view, odoo

I've a question concerning relational field in Odoo.

i have a relational field X into modelA (a Many2Many field) related with the modelB, i create a view (viewA.xml) for the ModelA, and i'd like to get acess to field (Y for example) located into modelB using my relational field (X). How to do that in xml view. i've tried to use the dot notation (X.Y), but it doesn't work in xml view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access Y only by using the list for X inside the view:

```
<field name="X">
    <tree>
        <field name="Y">
    </tree>
</field>
```